# How to show data as per users in Voyager Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, voyager

Voyager is one of the most efficient admin panel for laravel. But, here I am trapped in a typical situation. For example, I am using this admin panel for booking appointment. I want the admin to view all the records but the user to view, edit, delete only the records which he had added. I can insert my own Page there but that will increase the work as I have to create my own add, edit, and delete functionality along with the view. I just want to know the place where the data is fetched from database to display on the view page so that as per the login user I could manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this:

1. You need to add policy to your bread `php  artisan make:policy PostPolicy`
2. Inside the policy you can specify who can edit what depending on your logic